# Meteor Less trying to include test file causes error on cloud9 ide

Tags: meteor, less, cloud9-ide

Trying to get a project project working on Cloud9 IDE. For some reason it comes up with the following error:

```
=> Errors prevented startup:

    While processing files with less (for target web.browser):
    packages/compileLessBatch/plugin/compile-less.js:164:11: Failed to decode Less path: http://localhost:8081/test/browser/less/imports/urls2.less
    ...
```

I thought it was something to do with loading `node_modules` using less but I can't find any references within my project.

What's going on and how can I fix this error?

Comment: Temporary fix by deleting the test folder in `node_modules/less` directory

Comment: This could also be related to the part that references `http://localhost:8081/test/`. Cloud9 doesn't have a localhost so all code is served on `0.0.0.0`. Not sure how exactly you'd apply that here to fix it but I'd guess this is the issue.

Comment: yes I figured the lack of a localhost would be part of the issue. Just confused as to why it is an issue when tests aren't running. It looks like the project tries to package up all less files even in node_modules

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the less package ?

[less package from Atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/less)

Comment: Did a double check, for sanity because it is running okay on my local machine so would be strange if that was the case.